# DataSource ODBC connection error to PostgreSQL in Visual Studio C# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, postgresql

we are having a problem connecting to a PostgreSQL database. On one laptop we are using:

1. 64-bit Windows 8
2. 32-bit Visual Studio C# 2010
3. PostgreSQL version 9.0
4. 64bit ODBC driver for PostgresSQL Unicode(x64) 9.0.1

On one desktop computer we are using:

1. 64-bit Windows 7
2. 32-bit Visual Studio C# 2010
3. PostgreSQL version 9.4
4. 64bit ODBC driver for PostgresSQL Unicode(x64) 9.0.1

On the laptop, the typed datasets are working fine, but on the desktop, we get an error "Failed to call ODBC driver connection utility" when creating a typed dataset as well as "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" depending on whether we use an existing connection string or try to test out a newly created one.

In both cases we are connecting to a machine data source created in ODBC beforehand. The machine data source itself tests successfully and has no problems connecting to PostgreSQL.

We are a bit at a loss as to what would make the difference otherwise than the version of PostgreSQL and what would be the best way to resolve this?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: you can try using a 32-bit ODBC driver, I don't have any experience with Postgre but I know of several other applications that have had issues with ODBC, and moving to the 32 bit driver resolved the problem. Your error message from the desktop seems to suggest this as well.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Postgresql?

Comment: It sounds like you have managed to install the 32-bit driver in such a way as it's visible to 64-bit applications, or vice versa. How did you install the ODBC driver?